# Delete repeated characters in string column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, in the row `A;AC=a,a;AD=E;AE=W;AF=u,u;AG=Q;AH=R`, there is repeated “,a” and “,u”.

The output wanted is `A;AC=a;AD=E;AE=W;AF=u;AG=Q;AH=R`

It is quite hard to correct the repeated words in the 'info' column. I need to delete the comma and following character.

This is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C','A;AC=a,a;AD=E;AE=W;AF=u,u;AG=Q;AH=R','F','G'],
                  ['h','k','J','AB=k;AC=5,5;AD=E;AF=W;AG=y,y;AH=Q','L','M'],['O','P','Q','AC=k;AD=e;AE=E;AF=W;AG=y;AH=Q;AK=R','S','T'],
                  ['U','V','W','AC=a;AD=b;AE=r;AF=y;AG=Q;AH=R','Y','Z'],['U','V','W','AC=a;AD=b;AE=r,r;AF=y;AG=Q;AH=R','Y','Z']], columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','info','col4','col5'])
```

We get this result as the diagram.

[image]

For example, We see in the 'info' column, "AC=a,a" has a repeated a. We need delete "a" therfore we need to delete the comma too. In the same column, there is "AF=u,u", the "u" character is also repeated, we need to remove "u" and its comma.In the next row, we see "AC=5,5;AD=E;AF=W;AG=y,y", here there is two more character 5,y and their comma.

This the diagram that would be wanted result.

[image]

So how to get the final result?

Answer (score 3):

You can try regex back reference:

```
# \1 refers to the previously capture group
# updated
pattern = r'([^=,]+),(\1)'
# if you have more than two instances, e.g. a,a,a
# use
# pattern = r'([^=,]+),(\1)'


df['info'] = df['info'].str.replace(pattern, r'\1')
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3                                 info col4 col5
0    A    B    C  A;AC=a;AD=E;AE=W;AF=0.500;AG=Q;AH=R    F    G
1    h    k    J        AB=k;AC=5;AD=E;AF=W;AG=y;AH=Q    L    M
2    O    P    Q   AC=k;AD=e;AE=E;AF=W;AG=y;AH=Q;AK=R    S    T
3    U    V    W        AC=a;AD=b;AE=r;AF=y;AG=Q;AH=R    Y    Z
4    U    V    W        AC=a;AD=b;AE=r;AF=y;AG=Q;AH=R    Y    Z
```

Comment: what if the repeated part is "AF=0.500,0.500", then use \1, it still could not turn to AF=0.500

Comment: @AAlex see updated answer with a new pattern. The `AF=0.500` is in line 1.

Comment: I use your code but it does not change.  do you update the content ?

Comment: @AAlex sorry, I don't understand why the updated pattern wasn't included. Now it is.

Answer (score 1):

Regex .sub will also do the trick.

```
import regex as re
df['info'] = [re.sub(r'(.),\1', r'\1', x) for x in df['info'] ]
df
```

In this expression, (.) refers to any character group with one character, then we have a comma, and then \1 refers to that same character group again. So we sub in the character that fit that pattern.

Output

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3                                info col4 col5
0    A    B    C     A;AC=a;AD=E;AE=W;AF=u;AG=Q;AH=R    F    G
1    h    k    J       AB=k;AC=5;AD=E;AF=W;AG=y;AH=Q    L    M
2    O    P    Q  AC=k;AD=e;AE=E;AF=W;AG=y;AH=Q;AK=R    S    T
3    U    V    W       AC=a;AD=b;AE=r;AF=y;AG=Q;AH=R    Y    Z
4    U    V    W       AC=a;AD=b;AE=r;AF=y;AG=Q;AH=R    Y    Z
```

Comment: So how about "AF=0.500,0.500" and hope it turn to AF=0.500?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution based on a list comprehension and `split` and `join` functions.

```
df['info'] = [';'.join(e.split(',')[0] for e in d.split(';')) for d in df['info']]
```